# How to make dynamic text bold having tag <b> </b> in listview?

Tags: android, html, json, android-layout, android-listview

I'm developing an application in which I'm parsing `JSON` data and fixing the result in the listview. In `JSON` response I'm getting the following response:

```
{
"searchdata": {
    "webresult": [
        {
            "title": "<b>Android</b>",
            "desc": "Discover a new flavor of Jelly Bean <b>Android</b> 4.2 introduces a completely new camera experience, a new form of typing that helps you power ...",
            "link": "http://www.android.com/"
        },
        {
            "title": "<b>Android</b> (operating system) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
            "desc": "<b>Android</b> is a Linux -based operating system designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablet computers. Initially developed by <b>Android</b> ...",
            "link": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(mobile_phone_platform)"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

In `title` as you can see **Android** tags are coming. I want to make it bold.

Here is what I'm doing for fixing those response in the listview.

```
try {
    HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet("MY API");
ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);

JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(data);

JSONObject jSearchData = rootObj.getJSONObject("searchdata");

JSONArray jsonArray = jSearchData.getJSONArray("webresult");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String title = objJson.getString("title");
    String desc = objJson.getString("desc");
    String link = objJson.getString("link");

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("title", title);
    map.put("description", desc);
    map.put("link", link);

    searchList.add(map);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
}
```

By the above code I'm getting the response and storing them into `Hashmap`. After that I'm using custom layout for displaying the content. Following code helps me getting the values fixed in the layout.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
searchList, R.layout.list_row, new String[] { "title","description", "link" }, new int[] { R.id.title,R.id.desc, R.id.url });

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Here, is what it looks like when all things go well.

[image: Screenshot from device of the layout]

As you can see the `html` tags are coming. Can please anyone suggest how to make the text bold inside the `html` bold tags?

Any help will be appreciated for this.

Comment: you will need to make custom Adapter inside of Default or you can try it as : `map.put("title", HTML.fromHtml(title));` but i think this will not work

Comment: When I'm doing this getting error. I'm doing this `map.put("title", Html.fromHtml(title));` with `    The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Spanned)`

Comment: you have to option . First one : create an Custom Adapter inside . and Second is : try it after changing  HashMap to `HashMap<String, Spanned> map = new HashMap<String, Spanned>();`

Comment: Ok. But how can I add those into arraylist. Again giving me error at `searchList.add(map);` stating `The method add(HashMap<String,String>) in the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,Spanned>)`

Comment: you also need to change `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` to `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Spanned>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html) and set a `html` value to the `TextView` instead of plain text.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), searchList, R.layout.list_row, new String[] { "title","description", "link" }, new int[] { R.id.title,R.id.desc, R.id.url });
SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object object, String value) {
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) view).setText(Html.fromHtml(value));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

adapter.setViewBinder(binder);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Html.fromHtml() before you put in to Map

```
map.put("title", HTML.fromHtml(title));
map.put("description", HTML.fromHtml(desc));
map.put("link", HTML.fromHtml(link));
```

Comment: it doesn't work. `SimpleAdapter` calls `toString` so all markup information will be lost.

Comment: Getting error. Stating `The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Spanned)`. I'm doing something like this.

`Html.fromHtml(title);
 Html.fromHtml(desc);
 Html.fromHtml(link);

 map.put("title", Html.fromHtml(title));
 map.put("description", Html.fromHtml(desc));
 map.put("link", Html.fromHtml(link));`

Comment: As ρяσѕρєя K said you need to change hash map generic time HashMap<String, Spanned> map

Answer (score 1):

Just use SpannedString instead of normal string and then display it on TextView using setText().

**Example:**
SpannedString spannedText = new SpannedString(Html.fromHtml(value));
textView.setText(spannedText);

Answer (score 0):

In Adapter class while setting the title just try as fallow.

holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(searchList.getTitle)).